# "Error in Python Code: 'ModuleNotFoundError' when importing 'pandas'"

Tags: python, pandas, pip, modulenotfounderror, virtual-environment

I am encountering an issue while trying to run a Python script. The error message is 'ModuleNotFoundError', specifically related to the 'pandas' library. I have installed 'pandas' using pip, but the script still fails to recognize the module. I'm seeking guidance on resolving this import error.

I have installed 'pandas' using the command pip install pandas in my virtual environment. I verified the installation with pip show pandas, which displayed the correct version. However, when running my Python script, I receive the error 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas''. I expected the script to execute without any import-related issues after successfully installing 'pandas'.

Comment: Did you activate your virtual environment and then launched your script from there ? Have you tried running simply `python` from your venv and running command `import pandas` ?

Comment: How, exactly, are you running the code?  What is the exact command?  Are you using an IDE?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am having the same issue with numpy. If i have to create a virtual enviroment to fix it, why i am be able to download globally. I didn't understand the point. Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a virtual environment. That is for users who work on multiple isolated projects simultaneously. Most people only need one normal environemnt.

How to resolve:

1. Uninstall the virtual environment.
2. Install python to your system (if not already installed).
3. Install packages to your normal environment
4. Run the code in the normal environment